# How Do I Combined These Into an If Else Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help combining the following two if statements into a single if-else statement.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
<?php
if ( !is_page_template('page.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/<?php echo     $theme_color ?>.css"/>
<?php } ?>

<?php
if ( is_page_template('full-page-no-background.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/isuzu_ecommerce.css"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
<?php if ( !is_page_template('page.php') ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/<?php echo     $theme_color ?>.css"/>
<?php } elseif ( is_page_template('full-page-no-background.php') ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/isuzu_ecommerce.css"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.  I was more looking to test the page template only ones and serve the appropriate stylesheet.  Basically, I just wanted to test if the page template is "full-page-no-background" first and if true, serve it's stylesheet, if not then serve the other stylesheet.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same, but looks much cleaner:

```
<?php

$template_url = get_bloginfo('template_url');

if ( !is_page_template('page.php'))
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-style' href='$template_url/$theme_color.css'/>";

elseif ( is_page_template('full-page-no-background.php'))
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$template_url/isuzu_ecommerce.css'/>";

?>
```